# Can you hide only the menu bar on an Apache Superset dataset explore page?

Tags: hide, embed, apache-superset

My goal is to embed the dataset explore screen where the user can build charts as an iframe in a web application; the idea would be that the user cannot see the menu bar on the top such that they cannot navigate away from the dataset within this iframe because it would result in the scope of the iframe being different from the scope of the application around it if they change datasets. I found the answer on a different thread was to use the standalone=true query parameter, but using that setting on a dataset explore page it simply shows you the chart (which is empty until the user adds some dimensions and measures to the query). Embedding a dashboard seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try appending `?standalone=1` to the URL. You can find more details about in the superset documentation:
https://superset.apache.org/docs/creating-charts-dashboards/creating-your-first-dashboard/

[image]

You might find this article helpful too: https://www.tetranyde.com/blog/embedding-superset